# bluemix service creation timing out in DevOps Services

Tags: bash, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, devops, ibm-jazz

With Bluemix DevOps Services I want a deploy script that will always create a new service instance (for example I am deploying to QA stack).

My deploy script looks something like this:

```
echo "Deleting app ${CF_APP}"
cf delete "${CF_APP}" -f -r

if cf services | grep "Insights for Twitter-test" -q
then
  echo "Twitter Service found, deleting in order to create a new one."
  cf delete-service "Insights for Twitter-test" -f
else
  echo "Twitter Service doesn't exist yet, will create new one."
fi

echo "Creating new service instance for Twitter"
cf create-service twitterinsights Free "Insights for Twitter-test"

echo "Pushing app ${CF_APP}"
cf push "${CF_APP}"
```

Everytime I run it, the service creation part times out:

```
Server error, status code: 504, error code: 10001, message: Service instance Insights for Twitter-test: The request to the service broker timed out: https://provision-broker.ng.bluemix.net/bmx/provisioning/brokers/832dfb83-50e9-42b5-9516-ac54ab1eeaf4/v2/service_instances/c3a42482-398c-4148-bacb-297c1f6670ef?accepts_incomplete=true&plan_id=a888c333-41b6-4384-97d1-f89d11d48be9&service_id=4176989f-0bf7-4cf2-987a-6a57320744d1
```

If I manually run this script with the CF CLI it works fine.  Only in DevOps Services does the service creation time out.

For the moment I am not concerned with the fact that the Twitter service doesn't have any state, and that I might as well leave it.  Imagine a database service instead, that I want to ensure has been create anew.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it still failing? It seems more as a temporal issue between DevOps and Bluemix.